# Conveyor agent crossing allowed gap

Tags: anylogic

Update: link to simplified model with replicated error added

In simulation model of conveyor technology, we are using a conveyor object type roller and we are moving our custom agents of transporter type by convey block always to the next position on a conveyor (imagine this as a exit or entry point on conveyor). It happens in some random seeds, that our agents cross allowed gap and Anylogic shows following error.

[image]
[image]

*It always happens when some agent enters convey block, but the error occurs on two other transporters, when the one behind crosses the gap.* - THIS IS NO LONGER TRUE. Today it happened when there was no agent entering convey block. We did not find any way to ignore this error or to find a workaround. Anyone has any ideas how to resolve it ? Picture of actual situation added, pink conveyors are breaking gap, and error pops up. We also found out that gap is broken also before, but error does not pop up.

link to simple mode file with replicated error: https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/ceafcc2a-9a05-4bb9-a56f-a1c018698b16?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL

[image]

Comment: Suggest you share some more details of the actual problem and setup, this is not enough to help. What is different between the seeds, how does it look just before the error, ... Try to simplify the model to the minimum viable version where the problem still occurs (2 conveyors with agents between them...)

Comment: There are only few random things that do not influence it that much, otherwise we are runnign model with real data from few days of warehouse operations. To describe the difference in data I would have to go into statistics, and I am not allowed to do that. We also found out that the distance between two agents on conveyor is broken more times during the model run, but error does not go out. Just before the error, some transporters have to be close (on minimum gap) to each other and another transporter has to be entering convey block. Picture of conveyor with postion and agents added.

Comment: You will have to simplify and try it with fake data so you can replicate the problem in a simple environment

Comment: link to simplified version of model with replicated error at about 262600s https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/ceafcc2a-9a05-4bb9-a56f-a1c018698b16?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL

Comment: Anyone has any ideas how to resolve it or at least how to workaround ?